# Node Cheerio shows nothing as a result

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do web scraping but I'm having a hard time.

**The code:**

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

  request('https://firestorm-servers.com/en/community/armory/7/10/5097781', (error, response, html) => {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          const $ = cheerio.load(html);

          const asd = $('.capitalize', '#character_datas').text();

          console.log(asd);
      }
  });
```

**And that's the html structure:**

[image]

So my problem is that the result I get in the command prompt is empty - literally a blank line.

Thanks! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: if you are getting a blank line than that element might not have been populated with data, ie you are scraping a js enabled site and the content you want is actually loaded at runtime and not with the page request. You would need to use a library like phantom or similar to run the js of the site so that you can get the content

Comment: Oh, I see... Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: But as Bauke also points out in their answer you are using the wrong selector, you used an id selector when you should have used a class selector:`$('.capitalize', '.character_datas')` check that first to see if that is the actual reason for failure

Comment: Still results in a blank line. :\

Comment: Look at `html` before trying to parse it: you haven't logged in

Comment: I'm always logged in there. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to select a class and an ID:

`const asd = $('.capitalize', '#character_datas').text();`

When your HTML shows 2 classes:

`<div class="character_datas">` and `<h1 class="capitalize">`

Comment: Well, I changed `const asd = $('.capitalize', '#character_datas').text();` to `const asd = $('.character_datas').text();` but I still get a blank line as a result.

Comment: I don't 100% remember how Cheerio's `.text()` works, but I think it's because that `div` doesn't have any actual text in it, only HTML. Try doing `$('.character_datas > .capitalize').text()` if you're trying to select the `h1`.

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: Ah, I see why. When I head to the URL you're downloading, it redirects me to login. So you need to be able to authenticate, otherwise the response won't include any data you're trying to get.

Comment: Well, I'm logged in.

Comment: You are in your browser, but not in your program. Your program has no awareness of your browser's state.

Comment: Well, then I should try with pupetter or?

Comment: You can, there's various ways of doing it but I think that's outside the scope of this question. There's plenty of material and tutorials online to do this.